# Обработка нескольких одновременных событий VK на Python

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, события

Передомной стоит задача написать код бота на Python, который при входе в беседу VK будет отправлять приветствие, но с одной особенностью. Если пользователей за n-ый промежуток времени заходит несколько, допустим это будет 5 секунд, то приветствие будет затрагивать всех вошедших упоминанием в одном сообщении, а не писать для каждого отдельное, создавая лишний флуд.
Уже очень долго ищу решение, как это можно сделать, но на данный момент у меня получается лишь собрать всех вошедших в один список, а как его обработать через 5 секунд - большой вопрос.
Прошу оказать помощь.

Мой код выглядит примерно так:

```
invites = {}
if event.object.action == 'chat_invite_user':
    invites[event.object.peer_id] = [].append(event.object.member_id)
```

Возможно, даже этот код можно написать на много лучше, но у меня в голове пока только это.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поставь отложенный вызов функции в 5 секунд. Код будет работать так:

1. Заходит пользователе, через 5 секунд сработает функция приветствия
2. В течении следующих 5 секунд заходит какое-то количество человек
3. Через 5 секунд функция берет из списка пользователей, которые зашли и отправляет одно приветствие для всех

А вообще не вижу в этом смысла, так как ситуация, когда в беседу заходят сразу несколько человек за 5 секунд, очень редкая. Проще сделать приветствия для каждого пользователя отдельно

Comment: В том и дело, что в голове алгоритм есть, а как его реализовать на практике - не понимаю. Например, заходит один человек, запускается функция, которая ожидает 5 секунд, после заходит ещё несколько человек, но как сказать этой же вызванной функции, которая ожидает 5 секунд, что в список нужно добавить ещё пользователей? Ведь если просто запустить ещё раз эту функцию, то запуститься паралельно ещё одна и все.

Comment: Сделайте флаг, isWork = false, при первом вызове isWork=true, когда заходят пользователи, происходит проверка, что isWork=false, если true, то код не выполняется, после того, как прошло 5 секунд, функция вызывается и isWork = false

Comment: Спасибо, вот такое решение должно сработать, буду писать такую логику